# Проблема с передачей значений через $_SESSION

Tags: apache, php, linux

У меня есть два файла, которые тестирую на локалхосте (если надо, приведу данные phpinfo по сессиям)

```
<?php
echo 'session01.php<p>';
session_start();
$_SESSION['index'] = 12345;
echo '|'.$_SESSION['index'].'|';
?>
```

И второй

```
<?php
echo 'session02.php<p>';
session_start();
//$_SESSION['index'] = 12345;
echo '|'.$_SESSION['index'].'|';
?>
```

В результате второй ничего не выводит. В логах пишется следующее:

> `[Mon Dec 05 00:35:37 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  session_start(): open(/var/lib/php5/sess_jgprggkjckd91caua3mv06f4q3, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /var/www/xxx/session01.php on line 3`
>
> `[Mon Dec 05 00:35:37 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  Unknown: open(/var/lib/php5/sess_jgprggkjckd91caua3mv06f4q3, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0`
>
> `[Mon Dec 05 00:35:37 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php5) in Unknown on line 0`
>
> `[Mon Dec 05 00:35:37 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/xxx/favicon.ico`
>
> `[Mon Dec 05 00:35:58 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  session_start(): open(/var/lib/php5/sess_i6r1dlv5iuh0348lr155haifl4, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /var/www/xxx/session02.php on line 3`
>
> `[Mon Dec 05 00:35:58 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: index in /var/www/xxx/session02.php on line 5`
>
> `[Mon Dec 05 00:35:58 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  Unknown: open(/var/lib/php5/sess_i6r1dlv5iuh0348lr155haifl4, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0`
>
> `[Mon Dec 05 00:35:58 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php5) in Unknown on line 0`
>
> `[Mon Dec 05 00:35:59 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/xxx/favicon.ico`

И еще вопрос:

1. Выходит так, что сервер хранит значения ячеек $_SESSION на файлах в директории указанной в `session.save_path` (php.ini)?
2. Судя по логам, нужно дать доступ на чтение/запись серверу, но я даже не в курсе как это сделать :(...
3. Каждый раз, когда я вызываю `session_start()`; обновляется имя файла куда записывается значение ячейки `$_SESSION`?(для первого файла это было `/var/lib/php5/sess_jgprggkjckd91caua3mv06f4q3`, а для второго - `/var/lib/php5/sess_i6r1dlv5iuh0348lr155haifl4`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть вероятность, что в файле конфига **PHP.ini** по параметру сессия стартует сама.
Поройся в этом файле, поищи в нем конфиг сессий(*там 10-15 строк*).
В результате в кукисах не создается идентификатор сессии. Я тоже сталкивался недавно с похожей проблемой при разработке сервера мгновенных сообщений.
**Кстати, если ваш браузер не поддерживает куки, то сессия просто не сможет создаться(повторю, что там хранится её идентификатор.)**

Comment: изменил в пхп.ини значение парамтера отвечающего за кукисы.
все работает, но есть вопрос: на пхп.нет в документации написано про кукисы на стороне клиента, т.е. если я в сесиях буду хранить логин и пароль пользователя, то их можно будет подделать клиентом?

Comment: можно будет, и украсть можно будет, чтобы потом использовать, поэтому советуют хранить не сам пароль, а, например, его хеш-код, или временный идентификатор соединения (если актуален - значит вошел, иначе - требование авторизации) - по истечении некоторого времени, если клиент не был активен - этот идентификатор перестает быт актуальным

Comment: В кукисах хранится только идентификатор сессии, который указывает на сессию юзера, расположенную на серве) В кукях лучше не хранить приватные данные. MD5 - хоть и кодирует, но существует масса сервисов раскодирования =)

Comment: Понял, дурак, простите) Че-то правда сессию с куки перепутал))

Answer (score 3):

Еще старт сессии должен начинаться в первую очередь, т.е.

```
<?php
session_start();
echo ...
?>
```

Иначе сессия не стартанет как надо...

Comment: И куки здесь не при чем - если они отключены, то параметры сессии (вместе с идентификатором) передаются через GET (можно ли сделать, чтобы через POST - не знаю).
Старт сессии передает в заголовке страницы нужную информацию, т.е. если был вывод до старта, то заголовок уже послан, а значит сессия, как уже говорил, не стартанет как надо, и по вашему 3-ему пункту видно - на каждый вызов страницы - своя сессия, а должна быть одна на все.

Answer (score 1):

Apache не может писать во временную директорию( в которой и хранятся файлы сессий ), т.е. вам всего навсего необходимо изменить права на эту папку или прописать другую папку в php.ini (естественно у этой папки тоже должны быть выставлены соответствующие права).

Вот собственно и все.

Comment: добавил пользователя www-data и файлы начали добавляться. но в логах пишет 
    [Mon Dec 05 07:33:39 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: index in /var/www/xxx/session02.php on line 5

выходит что не видит ячейку массива.